# Failure to push Docker Image to Heroku Repository due to 'unauthorized access' error

Tags: docker, heroku, push

### I am trying to push a Docker image to the Heroku repository (web process), but am getting an authorisation issue (in trying to connect to the Heroku repo).  Am new to this area, so appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this matter.  Below is a screen grab which shows the error at the bottom.  To start, it shows that I have successfully built the Docker image and tagged it to heroku.  The directory I am running this in, and where the Dockerfile etc is stored is 'quote-app'.  Appreciate any help on this please -

```
Successfully built 74d28e1cf94a
Successfully tagged registry.heroku.com/quote-app/web:latest

jito76@jito76-VirtualBox:~/quote-app$ docker push registry.heroku.com/quote-app/web
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/quote-app/web]
3dc73b143d23: Preparing 
2c8df0ddcfaf: Preparing 
c73fe40e801c: Preparing 
6e9ea2b471fc: Preparing 
485a88bfb7a0: Preparing 
11b5066d94a5: Waiting 
bd8e6688d36c: Waiting 
07cab4339852: Waiting 
unauthorized: authentication required
jito76@jito76-VirtualBox:~/quote-app$
```

Comment: you might have to do a `docker login` and then push the image

Comment: Did you create the Heroku application using `heroku create` command?

Comment: I have changed my answer, I think it is a problem with the application name, please have a look, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The application name `quote-app` does not match the Heroku application name: this happens when creating the Heroku app from the command line  (`heroku create` without additional parameters)

It is better to set the application name explicitly

```
$ heroku create quote-app

$ docker build -t registry.heroku.com/quote-app/web .
$ docker push registry.heroku.com/quote-app/web
$ heroku container:release web -a quote-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions peeps.  I did login using the 'heroku container:login' command, and it stated that I had "logged in successfully" when I ran the command.  I am running the docker commands from the Ubuntu directory, that the container/app is stored in, instead of running it from home or as 'root' user.  Hence, Am wondering whether I have the right Linux user rights to execute the code from there.  Otherwise, am out of ideas for now

Answer (score 0):

I was doing trial and error and this sorted out the auth issue, not sure what exactly did the magic:

```
heroku login

heroku stack:set container -a 

heroku container:push worker -a 

heroku container:login

heroku container:push worker -a
```

Remember to enter your Heroku App name after `-a`.